# Possible bug: Upvotes lowers question score

Tags: bug, votes

So just now I upvoted [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/168717/30062) from Old Lamplighter (Richard). However, I noted that an upvote actually decreases the score of the question by 1. Same thing for the response by user Colleen V from 89 to 88 rather than to 90.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Logs show no downvotes in your timeframe for Colleen, 1 downvote on the entire day for Old Lamplighter. Odds of downvotes being the cause are slim. I'd assume a strange graphical glitch or potentially people reversing their upvotes during a grace period. I'd slap a "could not reproduce" on this and not worry about it unless you see it happening again.

Answer (score 3):

In both users' reputation history, I see an 'unupvote' around the same time, and an 'upvote' around that time as well. That might explain why the score didn't increase, but not why it decreased:

[Old Lamplighter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/46894/old-lamplighter?tab=reputation):

[image]

[Colleen V](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/26699/colleenv?tab=reputation):

[image]

Perhaps it's a [caching issue](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: That was done by me to test whether it was a glitch or not.